# Error opening CA private key when Create the intermediate pair

Tags: openssl

I follow this [tutorial](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-root-pair.html) to Create the root pair and Create the intermediate pair.

Create the root pair is fine, but when i try to Create the intermediate pair it's error at this line:

```
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -extensions v3_intermediate_ca \
      -days 3650 -notext -md sha256 \
      -in intermediate/csr/intermediate.csr.pem \
      -out intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem
```

with error is:

```
Error opening CA private key /root/ca/private/ca.key.pem
140382210524824:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/root/ca/private/ca.key.pem','r')
140382210524824:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
unable to load CA private key
```

I follow step by step and check so many time but really don't know why. What am i missing? Someone know please give me some advice

Comment: Can you see the ca's private key file? `ls /root/ca/private/ca.key.pem` should tell you.

Comment: yes, i can see this file

Comment: hey someone can tell me why

Comment: The issue is definitely in the `openssl.conf`, so double-check the `openssl.conf`, as it likely either has the wrong value, or double values, for `private_key`.  If you're using the default `openssl.conf`, it's one of the most difficult config files to make sense of and navigate through... you may want to reference [this](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSL/Linux/openssl.cnf) one, as I created it with the focus being on making it far less complicated of a config _(all info and commands start on Line 430)_

Comment: Have you viewed the file to see if it is a private key in PEM format?  Or run `openssl rsa -check -noout -in /root/ca/private/ca.key.pem` to check if it's a valid key.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, i will check it's at tomorrow

Comment: when i run: *openssl rsa -check -noout -in /root/ca/private/ca.key.pem* it's show: RSA key is OK

Comment: I found problem, it't wrong path, I edit and it't work fine, thank you